# i am using a logic to create a search box s but from webservice i am getting json object and i am not able to convert that json into array

Tags: angular

I have a json file which I have added here.I am trying to populate json data into three dropdown.I am able to just get the first bank data in the dropdown ,not for all the banks mentioned in the json.

modal component.ts

```
  ngOnInit() {
this.searchserv.getBankJson().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.banks = data["banks"];
        this.cities = this.banks[Object.keys(this.banks)[0]];
         this.branches= this.cities[Object.keys(this.cities)[0]];

        console.log(this.banks);
        },
          (error) => console.log("error : " + error),
          () => console.log('completed')
        );

       }

       firstDropDownChanged(val: any) {
      let obj= this.banks;
    console.log(obj.length);
    //for(let i = 0 ;i<obj.length;i++){
    //console.log( obj);
    //}
    if (!obj) return;


    if (obj == this.banks) {
      this.city = this.cities [Object.keys(this.cities["cities"])[0]];

      console.log("cities are ="+ this.city);
    }

  }
   secondDropDownChanged(val: any) {
    let obj = this.banks["CITY"];
    console.log(val, obj);

    if (!obj) return;

    if (obj == this.cities) {
      this.branch = this.branches[Object.keys(this.branches)[0]];

      console.log(this.branch);
    }
    }

  }

my json file 

{
  "banks": {
    "SBI": {
            "cities": {
                       "Bangalore": {
                                      "branches": {
                                                    "rrnamgar1": "SBIN100000","rrnamgar2": "SBIN100000"
  }
  },"Hyderabad": {
                                      "branches": {
                                                    "rrnamgar1": "SBIN100000","rrnamgar2": "SBIN100000"
  }
  }
  }
  },
  "CBI": {
            "cities": {
                       "Bangalore": {
                                      "branches": {
                                                    "rrnamgar1": "SBIN100000","rrnamgar2": "SBIN100000"
  }
  },"Hyderabad": {
                                      "branches": {
                                                    "rrnamgar1": "SBIN100000","rrnamgar2": "SBIN100000"
  }
  }
  }
  },
  "HDFC": {
            "cities": {
                       "Bangalore": {
                                      "branches": {
                                                    "rrnamgar1": "SBIN100000","rrnamgar2": "SBIN100000"
  }
  },"Hyderabad": {
                                      "branches": {
                                                    "rrnamgar1": "SBIN100000","rrnamgar2": "SBIN100000"
  }
  }
  }
  },
  "BOI": {
            "cities": {
                       "Bangalore": {
                                      "branches": {
                                                    "rrnamgar1": "SBIN100000","rrnamgar2": "SBIN100000"
  }
  },"Hyderabad": {
                                      "branches": {
                                                    "rrnamgar1": "SBIN100000","rrnamgar2": "SBIN100000"
  }
  }
  }
  },
  "IDFC": {
            "cities": {
                       "Bangalore": {
                                      "branches": {
                                                    "rrnamgar1": "SBIN100000","rrnamgar2": "SBIN100000"
  }
  },"Hyderabad": {
                                      "branches": {
                                                    "rrnamgar1": "SBIN100000","rrnamgar2": "SBIN100000"
  }
  }
  }
  }
 }
}
```

I am using pipe to convert the data into array and then use it.

Please help me on this.

Comment: I deleted my answer since it only apparently answered one of your questions. These are two completely different questions, so you could consider making two separate questions perhaps. But it's up to you :)

Comment: i will make that as a separate one  .

Comment: I have made it into a separate question .Please help me on this. Thanks in Advance

Comment: hey AJT_82. Can you help me on this?

Comment: you need just each bank name in separate drop-down from the JSON Object

Comment: How to achieve that?

Comment: I have to show bank name in the first drop down .In the second name I have to show the city names only and in the third one i have to show the branches  name

Comment: Hi Balajivaishnav .Can you help me out on this?